# Problems with sorting datetime column of DataTables Angular

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm using DataTables + Angular

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

I have troubles with the sorting of Datetime column. The formats that i need are dd/mm/yyyy and hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy, I tried to define

```
      columnDefs: [
          { type: 'date-uk', targets: 0 }
       ]
```

but it is not working, I think that the plugin date-uk doesn't work with the angular way. 
are there Someone who is using Datatables with the angular way and that to have to sort any date column ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item in yourArray | orderBy:'date':true track by $index